# Replace Dates in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I would like to replace each version old number in a file with a new one. For example 1.12.5 with 1.13.

My solution so far is this command: `sed -i '' -e "s/1.12.5/1.13/g" file.txt`

For now I have the problem that this command also replaces the numbers, if they appear separately in a line, e.g. `blabla 1.12.5blablabf1b12b5blabla -> blabla 1.13blablabf1.13blabla`
However it should return `blabla 1.13blablabf1b12b5blabla`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

***Generic solution:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/1.13/' Input_file
```

***Specific solution:*** Above is generic one, in case you want to go for specific version then you need to escape `.` to make it as a literal character to be treated.

```
sed 's/1\.12\.5/1.13/' Input_file
```

Please use `-i` option with `sed` to save output into Input_file itself.

Answer (score 2):

Dot is special in sed regexes. It means "any character". Backslash it for literal meaning:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/1\.12\.5/1.13/g'
```